# How to setup svn with nginx that can be checked out via http protocol?

Tags: nginx, svn

I am trying to setup a SVN on my linode server (Debian).

https://library.linode.com/linux-tools/version-control/svn I found an article here but it only tells me how to setup with Apache. I am using Nginx instead, how do I set up?

I hope to set up my own SVN server and check out the files via `http://` protocol, rather than `svn+ssh://`

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Subversion can't be served from nginx directly as the latter doesn't support PROPFIND method.
Your only chance is to proxy DAV clients to a more feature full server. I.e. Apache HTTPD.